# Remove elements from LinkedHashMap in parallel

Tags: java, fork-join

Let's say I have huge LinkedHashMap, I need to remove elements from the list in parallel based on some predicate.

Filling map

```
    Map<Long, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (long i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE / 1000; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(sb.append(UUID.randomUUID().toString())));
        }
        map.put(i, sb.toString());
    }
```

Trying to remove element using single thread loop.

```
    Iterator<Entry<Long, String>> it = maps.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().getValue().indexOf(SEARCH_STR) != -1) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Trying to do it in parallel (Just an example which works slowly)

```
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    long to = 0, from = 0, size = map.size();
    do {
        to += 550000;
        to = Math.min(to, size);
        long _from = from, _to = to;
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(()-> {
            for (Entry<Long, String> entry : map.subMap(_from, _to).entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().indexOf(SEARCH_STR) == -1) {
                    synchronized (result) {
                        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        from = to;
        futures.add(future);
    } while (to < size);

    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }
```

Can I achieve better performance using Java 8 `ForkJoinPool` or `ParallelStream` ? Code below simply goes OOM

```
    Map<Long, String> result = originalMap.entrySet().parallelStream()
            .filter((k) -> k.getValue().indexOf(SEARCH_STR) != -1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((k) -> k.getKey(), (v) -> v.getValue()
    ));
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I missed anything but where exactly are you *Removing* the element in parallel?

Comment: Well I do not remove, i'm putting the results into the new map to simplify example. Remove can be done as well, but I believe additional synchronization is needed to avoid throwing IndexOfBoundException by subMap method.

Comment: You should write a quick implementation for micro-benchmarking both the approaches with a relatively large size of array to compare the results and then choose an approach with suits your application.

Comment: Coding from the couch, I think this is what you want?  Maybe?  `result = map.stream().parallel().filter((k,v) -> v.indexOf(SEARCH_STR) == -1).collect(Collectors::toMap)`.  Although, that is for your second example, not your first.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Can removal be done instead of creation of new map to avoid additional memory allocation ? Also need to test it whether to original order will be keept

Comment: `removeIf(...)` is what you want, but that doesn't work on streams.   You'd need `map.values().removeIf(value -> value.indexOf(SEARCH_STR) != -1)`.   But this is not parallel.

Comment: Doesn't the use of LinkedHashMap essentially rule out parallel processing of its elements since it is inherently serial in nature?

Comment: Removing from a stream is not possible, because the stream operations must be non-interfering; they can't change the source of the stream.  So, you can't modify a collection via a stream (parallel or otherwise), only collect a processed (filtered) version.  If you want to avoid copying the data, `ParallelStream` is out.

Comment: @user12384512 you absolutely _cannot do this._  You cannot modify a `LinkedHashMap` in parallel at all; if you try your program will basically explode.  Random `NullPointerException`s, infinite loops, nonsensical data...all of these can happen and probably will, and there's no way of predicting what.  `LinkedHashMap` is not thread safe.  @AJNeufeld's approach will work, though I'd use `Collectors.toConcurrentMap` which will perform better.

Comment: Consider using immutable data types instead. Languages that provide this kind of features (e.g. Clojure) usually use immutable data types to avoid most/all problems related with concurrency. Of course this means you do not modify the original linked list but construct a new one based on the original.

Comment: as mentioned above, `LinkedHashMap` is being used for certain reasons , and indeed it's not the most optimal map to remove data in parallel. If you check the Oracle's [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html),it does need external synchronization.A fast solution would be to effectively cut in pieces the initial Map,against a stabilized number of threads , and scatter the Map so that each thread would have a specific number of elements to process and at the end re-join the sub-maps to a big one. If you also do that over a batch , might save some memory space